# Solr , how to boost based on 2 conditons

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

If I need to boost the most recent documents first, I can use

> bf=recip(rord(creationDate),1,1000,1000)

OR

> bq={!func}recip(rord(creationDate),1,1000,1000)

But I need to add another condition to this that I want to boost only those recent docs which has the price between 1 TO 100 . How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

we can do that by simple AND query.

> bq=( {!func}recip(rord(creationDate),1,1000,1000) AND price:[1 TO
>   100])